# HtmlUnit to take snapshot of Ajax applications

Tags: java, gwt, htmlunit, googlebot, google-crawlers

I create a basic GWT (Google Web Toolkit) Ajax application, and now I'm trying to create [snapshots to the crawlers read the page](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification).

I create a Servlet to response the crawlers, using HtmlUnit.

My application runs perfectly when I'm on a browser. But when in HtmlUnit, it throws a lot of errors about the special chars I have in the HTML. But these chars are content, and I wouldn't like to replace it with the special codes, once it's currently working, just because of the HtmlUnit. (at least I should check before if I'm using HtmlUnit correctly )

[image: My page with the error]

I think HtmlUnit should read the charset information of the page and render it as a browser, once it's the objective of the project I think.

I haven't found good information about this problem. Is this an HtmlUnit limitation? Do I need to change all the content of my website to use this java library to take snapshots?

Here's my code:

```
if ((queryString != null) && (queryString.contains("_escaped_fragment_"))) {
            // ok its the crawler
            // rewrite the URL back to the original #! version
            // remember to unescape any %XX characters

            url = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");

            String ajaxURL = url.replace("?_escaped_fragment_=", "#!");


            final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);


            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(ajaxURL);

            // important!  Give the headless browser enough time to execute JavaScript
            // The exact time to wait may depend on your application.
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(3000);

            // return the snapshot
            response.getWriter().write(page.asXml());
```

Comment: Did you set the encoding in your host page?

Comment: Yes, for sure. UTF8. HtmlUnit works nice if I remove special chars like 'ç'.

Comment: Are you certain that 'ç' is encoded in utf-8, and that this isn't HtmlUnit's way of warning you that you are being inconsistent? Where does that character come from - is it in the compiled html/js, or is it part of a response from a call to the server when rendering the page?

Comment: Also, are you *certain* that htmlunit is the source of this error and not the browser itself? A quick search of the text in your error doesn't seem to be specific to htmlunit, but instead suggests a xhtml doctype.

Comment: @ColinAlworth oh, maybe you are right. I call asXml() method from HTML unit, and this can be confliting with the header metatag of the original xml. I'll check it...

Comment: @ColinAlworth it's not confliting. It are printing the encode correctly. If HtmlUnit read UTF8, it should output UTF-8 as well. I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was XML confliting with the HTML. @ColinAlworth comments helped me.

I followed Google example, and there was not working.

To it work, you need to remove XML tags and let just the HTML be responded, changing the line:

```
 // return the snapshot
 response.getWriter().write(page.asXml());
```

to

```
 response.getWriter().write(page.asXml().replaceFirst("<\\?.*>",""));
```

Now it's rendering.

But although it is being rendered, the CSS is ot working, and the DOM is not updated (GWT updates page title when page opens). HTMLUnit throwed a lot of errors about CSS, and I'm using twitter bootstrap without any changes. Apparently, HtmlUnit project have a lot of bugs, good for small tests, but not to parse complex (or even simple) HTMLs.

Comment: Remember too that HtmlUnit is not actually rendering content in a visible way. This implies that it doesn't actually need to know about all modern CSS - though of course it is handy if it does know, so that you can sanity check your app. As long as it returns the right content, I wouldn't worry about it not knowing how to render that same content. If you want to back your server with a real-er browser, look into PhantomJS - it is a native binary, but is a headless chromium build that even lets you take screenshots.

Comment: @ColinAlworth, I get the asXml() output and open in my browser, it was completly different from the Chrome. In GWT, you set the page title dinamically calling methods of the framework that results in javascript. HTMLUnit doesn't returned the updated DOM after these javascripts ajax methods be executed. I don't know how people have ajax websites are doing to crawlers do their job well.